# Does Perl's $| setting affect system commands?

Tags: perl, buffering

I am looking at some old code in Perl, where the author has writtern 
`$| = 1` in the first line.

But the code does not have any print statements, it calls a C++ binary using the `system` command. Now I read that `$|` will force flush after every print. So does it affect the system command's output in any way or am I safe to remove that line.

Thanks
Arvind

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I do not believe so.  The $| will affect the way that Perl is running, not any external executable.

You should be safe to remove it.

[perldoc - perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html) : States "*If set to nonzero, forces a flush right away and after every write or print on the currently selected output channel.*".  I think the important thing here is the "**currently selected output channel**".  The external application will have it's own output channel.

Answer (score 5):

With questions like this it is often easy to write a trivial program that shows what the behavior is:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

if (@ARGV) {
    output();
    exit;
}

print "in the first program without \$|:\n";
output();

$| = 1;
print "in the first program with \$|:\n";
output();

print "in system with \$|\n";
system($^X, $0, 1) == 0
    or die "could not run '$^X $0 1' failed\n";

$| = 0;
print "in system without \$|\n";
system($^X, $0, 1) == 0
    or die "could not run '$^X $0 1' failed\n";

sub output {
    for my $i (1 .. 4) {
        print $i;
        sleep 1;
    }
    print "\n";
}
```

From this we can see that setting `$|` has no affect on programs run through `system`.

Answer (score 5):

This is something that you can easily check yourself. Create a program where buffering matters, like printing a series of dots. You should see the output all at once after ten seconds since the output is buffered:

```
#!perl

foreach ( 1 .. 10 )
    {
    print ".";
    sleep 1;
    }

print "\n";
```

Now, try setting `$|` and calling this with `system`:

```
 % perl -e "$|++; system( qq|$^X test.pl| )";
```

For my test case, the $| value didn't affect the buffering in the child process.